# Embedding Office files (.doc, .ppt, .xls) in my Android App

Tags: android, api, sdk, ms-office, quickoffice

Is there a way to embed any kind of a viewer (for exapmle, QuickOffice Viewer) 
inside an Android App, in order to view/show/edit Documents such as .docx, pptx, xlsx, etc. (Word, Excel, PowerPoint files) ?

Any SDK or any API to present those **without** leaving to another app ?

A.K.A 
I don't want my files & data to leave my app, but I want them be presented to the user :)

Comment: Have you solved your problem and achieved what your looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`Apache POI`](http://poi.apache.org/).

> The Apache POI Project's mission is to create and maintain Java APIs
>   for manipulating various file formats based upon the Office Open XML
>   standards (OOXML) and Microsoft's OLE 2 Compound Document format
>   (OLE2).

Then, there is [`Aspose`](http://www.aspose.com/android/total-component.aspx) which offers APIs to work with MS Office and other documents like PDF, etc.

Comment: I saw that POI project! but it is only for old 97-2003 office docs..
That could have been really cool though :(
Tnx.

Comment: @zaxy78 `Aspose` then?

Comment: Actually `Aspose` looks great!
they cost money, but it's exactly what I need :)   Thanks!

Comment: Aspose link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no such libraries which can embed these documents in your app while you may create your own Like for viewing PDF Java's iText Library will be perfect and similarly for others.