# Opening ppts in my android app

Tags: android, powerpoint

I have created an android application in which I want to add a feature for viewing ppts without he user having to download it first. As in, opening a ppt on the phone browser. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate better.
if what you mean is what i am thinking.

Maybe for a user to be able to view ppt files in your app.

- Try using APIs, or ppt supported sdks. [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486436/embedding-office-files-doc-ppt-xls-in-my-android-app)